# Why does my custom UITextField look like different at Interface Builder vs in running on device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

Hi everyone I'm a bit new to swift .

I wanna subclass UITextField and add extra features in order to create my own new TextField , I've  modified TextField's border by creating a a new  instance of CALayer to create a new underline border so

I'm running problem with my textfield that is my TextField looks like different in InterfaceBuild VS when running on device  as shown below in photo ?

I've tried to called setborder func in prepareForInterfaceBuilder but that didn't work for me 
so my first question is what should i do to fix this problem ?

the second  what is the difference between  calling  my func setborder in init func vs draw func ?

[TextFieldPhoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK6pF.png)
[attributes inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tknvq.png)
thanks in advance

```
import FontAwesome_swift

@IBDesignable
class NewUITextField: UITextField {


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setBorder()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setBorder()

    }


    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        var txtRec = super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)

        txtRec.origin.x += leftPadding

        return txtRec
    }




    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }


    @IBInspectable  var leftPadding : CGFloat  = 0


    @IBInspectable  var borderColor :UIColor = UIColor.lightGray {

        didSet{

            setBorder()

        }
    }

    @IBInspectable  var borderWidth : CGFloat = 0.4 {

        didSet{
            setBorder()
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable  var leftImage : UIImage? {

        didSet{
            setleftImage()
        }
    }



    func setBorder()  {


        let border = CALayer()

        let width = CGFloat(self.borderWidth)


        border.borderColor =  self.borderColor.cgColor    //UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width

        self.borderStyle = .none

        self.layer.addSublayer(border)

        self.layer.masksToBounds = true




    }


    func setleftImage()  {

        if let img = leftImage{

            self.leftViewMode = .always

            let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

            imgView.image = img


            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            imgView.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray

            self.leftView = imgView

        }
        else {

            self.leftViewMode = .never

            self.leftView = nil
        }
    }


    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        setBorder()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean borders? Please share your textField's attributes inspector in `Interface Builder`.

Comment: @EmreCiftci yes I meant the borders , I've edited the post to add  attributes inspector in Interface Builder

Comment: @EmreCiftci  thanks for the first issue has resolved what about the second question ?

Answer (score 0):

hi i am getting expected output in interface builder, without changing any code given by you.

please check attached image [image: Interface Image]

and For getting the same please check below image of attribute inspector has **Up to date** status as shown in image

[image: Uptodate Attribute]

if you don't get Up To date status then please select Editor -> Refresh All Views from menu
[image: Menu selection]

also make sure you have **deselected** few option to see expected o/p from Editor -> Canvas -> Show Layout Rectangles and Show Bound Rectangles
[image]

Comment: I've deselected (Layout Rectangles and Show Bound Rectangles) and that fix the first issue thanks you do you have any idea about the second one ?

Comment: can you tell me at where you have override prepareForInterfaceBuilder method?

Comment: ok so for prepareForInterfaceBuilder , Interface Builder instantiates a class with the IB_DESIGNABLE attribute, it calls this method to let the resulting object know that it was created at design time. You can implement this method in your designable classes and use it to configure their **design-time appearance**.   So its for design time  if you comment both init method then it will work on IB only not runtime.  for more please check below link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402908-prepareforinterfacebuilder

Comment: thank you for your reply but I meant   what is the difference between calling my func setborder in init func vs draw func ?